# how to synchronise data with JNI in android

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I need to synchronize on a structure, which will be filled in native code(C code) and the same will be read from the Java Code with JNI. I need to synchronize these. Is there any method I should use, something like the IPC mechanisms?

Comment: You need to use locking in the C space. IPC is one option if that is supported on your device. What locking mechanisms are available to you in C?

Comment: Hey Android007, I am doing a project that seems like it does similar things as yours. I was wondering if you wouldn't mind sharing your code or at least how you get the bitmap to continuously update. Right now I create a single bitmap from a randomly generated color array, and would like to update it at about 15 fps. My email is mmeisner204@gmail.com Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JNIEnv to acquire the monitor for a Java Object and therefor use the usual Java synchronization to synchronize.. More on the monitor entry and exit [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html)

Comment: any examples on how to use them? Because I can't find them anywhere and I am a very beginner to JAVA.

Comment: I do not have any simple code sample I can share [this](http://www.lkn.ei.tum.de/arbeiten/faq/man/JAVA-tutorial/native1.1/implementing/sync.html) probably explains the use a bit better